# Camel rest-dsl request returns 404

Tags: rest, apache-camel

Following a simple camel rest-dsl

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="netty4-http" port="8080" host="localhost"/>
    <rest path="/mycontext">
        <get uri="/foo">
            <to uri="direct:fooService"/>
        </get>
    </rest>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:fooService"/>
        <to uri="netty4-http:http://localhost:9773/services/foo"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

when I invoke  `curl localhost:8080/mycontext/foo` it always returns 404 with the following exception:

```
org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpOperationFailedException: Netty HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:9773/services/foo with statusCode: 404
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpHelper.populateNettyHttpOperationFailedException(NettyHttpHelper.java:160)
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpProducer$NettyHttpProducerCallback.done(NettyHttpProducer.java:111)
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyProducer$NettyProducerCallback.done(NettyProducer.java:491)
at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ClientChannelHandler.channelRead0(ClientChannelHandler.java:189)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
```

When I took the packet capture, I see that the request line is incorrect

```
GET http://localhost:9773/services/foo HTTP/1.1
```

but when I hit the back-end directly the request line is `GET /services/foo HTTP/1.1`

Could someone please help me figuring out the issue

Comment: You may try setting the URI to invoke within the `Exchange.HTTP_URI` header beforehand or try to set `&bridgeEndpoint=true` as a property. As [documented](http://camel.apache.org/netty4-http.html) Camel will remove any component properties before invoking the actual URI. Not sure though if this solves your problem

Comment: unfortunately, the issues still exits :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct.

```
<to uri="netty4-http:http://localhost:9773/services/foo"/>
```

The netty component as mentioned in the documentation deals with TCP/UDP communication and not HTTP. In any case the URI is also wrong.

You can for example write for TCP:

```
 <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5022?textline=true&amp;sync=true&amp;workerPool=#sharedPool&amp;usingExecutorService=false"/>
  <to uri="log:result"/>
```

Look at http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html for explanation on this. If you do want to do HTTP communication then use jetty or Restlet.